# Odoo v11: How to pass a parameter to cron job

Tags: odoo-11

Here's my code snippet. I want to pass param1 to cron job.

How do I do that?

```
class MyTask(models.Model):

    _name = "my.task"

    @api.model
    def cron_do_task(self, param1)
       print(param1)

<record id="cron_do_task" forcecreate='True' model="ir.cron">
      <field name="name">Do -Task</field>
      <field eval="False" name="active"/>
      <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root"/>
      <field name="interval_number">15</field>
      <field name="interval_type">minutes</field>
      <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
      <field name="model_id" ref="model_my_task"/>
      <field name="state">code</field>
      <field name="code">model.cron_do_task(???)</field>
</record>
```

I believe `args` is no more available in v11

Comment: Do you know the parameter value beforehand?

Comment: @ChesuCR No, I don't.

Comment: Then, where is the parameter stored?